# MySQL echo while

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

Hello guys I am working on a dynamic website and I am have some trouble when I try to echo the results.
If someone can help me I would be very appreciated.

```
<?php 
$page = "SELECT * FROM Paginas";
$execute = $connect->query($page);
$pagename = $execute->fetch_all(MYSQL_ASSOC);
if ($connect->$page !== false){
    $maximo = "SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Paginas";
    $execute1 = $connect->query($maximo);
    $i = 0;
    while ($i <= $execute1){ 
        echo "<li><a href=#" . $pagename[$i]['Nome'] . ">".$pagename[$i]['Nome'] ."</a></li>";
        $i++;
    }
}
?>
```

The problem Is I have 3 ID pages but it only show 2 of them.
I have

```
ID 1 - Home
ID 2 - HardSecure
ID 3 - Services
```

all filled correctly on data base but the while loop doesnt retrive it .

Comment: `while ($i  $execute1){ ` what is your goal with this?

Comment: @Qirel I paste wrong its <=

Comment: change the while to be `while ($row = $execute1)` then you can use row however you want

Comment: That doesn't make sense though, you're comparing an integer to a boolean, and why do you need to execute the second query?

Comment: `SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Paginas` only returns one row, why do you think you need a loop in the first place?

Comment: @Qirel The first one is to select all information from Table Paginas the seccond one is to select max id so I can use as while limit

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález The loop is too print the navigation <a href> with the mysql information

Comment: You don't need to limit the while, it will stop iteration when its fetched everything if you do it right.

Comment: @Qirel can u give me an example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to generate menu for page items?
I don't know what you are trying to do with $maximo? are you trying to get the last page or something?

Any way if you want to generate menu items then this should work better:

```
<?php 
$query = "SELECT * FROM Paginas";
$execute = $connect->query($query);
$result = $execute->fetch_all(MYSQL_ASSOC);
if (is_array($result) && !empty($result)){
  foreach($result as $page){
    echo '<li><a href="#'.$page['Nome'].'">'.$page['Nome'].'</a></li>';
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some things in your code which doesn't make much sense, particularity the argument to your `while` (`$i <= $execute1` compares an integer to a boolean) and your argument to the `if` (`$connect->$page !== false` tries to use the query-string as a property of your mysqli-object).

You should also not use `MAX()` as a reliable way to know when you've fetched all the rows, as that might return the number 3, but if you only have 2 records (for an example), the `MAX()` isn't accurate and will provide you with the wrong result. The ID may not be continuous in your table if one row is modified or deleted.

You should either use `fetch_assoc()` as the argument of the while, or stay with `fetch_all()` and use a `foreach`. In any case, it will loop over all the rows returned, and stop looping once its iterated over every row. I'll use the first.

```
$page = "SELECT * FROM Paginas";
if ($execute = $connect->query($page)) 
    while ($row = $execute->fetch_assoc()) { 
        echo "<li><a href=#" . $row['Nome'] . ">".$row['Nome'] ."</a></li>";
    }
}
```

You should refer to the manual of each function for further details. I recommend you read up on each function and understand what they actually do, as this will help you further building your application.

- http://php.net/mysqli.query
- http://php.net/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc
- http://php.net/mysqli-result.fetch-all

Comment: Indeed, no need to complicate it more than necessary ;-) *Cheers*

Comment: exactly, and it's the only answer that realises the return type is an object xD

Answer (score 0):

Don't use while, use foreach each:

```
foreach($pagename as $row) {
    echo "<li><a href=#" . $row['Name'] . ">".$row['Name'] ."</a></li>";
}
```

Comment: worth noting ^ will only work if $pagename is equal to array - this will break with objects